# Thread pass data and window close

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, excel

I have created a simple WPF project where on button click I create a separate thread with new window, and pass data to it. On application Exit I am trying to close safely that thread/window. However, I get occasionally the bellow exception, which causes application instabilities.
So my question is how to handle that situation gracefully. Thx

On line:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
```

I have

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll  
Additional information: Thread was being aborted.
```

My View has the following code:

Constructor

```
public MyView(ConcurrentQueue<MyItem> actionReports, ManualResetEvent actionCompletedEvent, string actionName)
{
    _actionReports = actionReports;
    _actionCompletedEvent = actionCompletedEvent;
    _actionName = actionName;

    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;

    this.Loaded += MyView_Loaded;
}

void MyView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (_actionCompletedEvent.WaitOne(0))
            {
         // Issue
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    Close();
                }));

                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            while (!_actionReports.IsEmpty)
            {
                // Do some stuff
            }
        }
    };

    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Initialize of Window

```
public WindowLauncher(ManualResetEvent actionCompletedEvent, ManualResetEvent reportWindowClosedEvent, string actionName)
{
    _actionCompletedEvent = actionCompletedEvent;
    _reportWindowClosedEvent = reportWindowClosedEvent;
    _actionName = actionName;

    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        _reportWindow = new MyView(_messageQueue, _actionCompletedEvent, actionName);
        _reportWindow.Show();

        // InvokeShutdown to terminate the thread properly
        _reportWindow.Closed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            _reportWindow.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        };
        _resetEvent.Set();
        Dispatcher.Run();
    }));

    thread.Name = "MyWindowThread";
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd normally at least try to cancel the `BackgroundWorker` async action in the `Window.OnClosing` event and catch the pending cancellation. You'll still need to watch out for ThreadAbortExceptions but only if your async process is long-running.

```
private BackgroundWorker _worker;

private void MyView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    _worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (_actionCompletedEvent.WaitOne(0))
            {
                if (_worker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    ea.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }

                // Issue
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    Close();
                }));

                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            while (!_actionReports.IsEmpty)
            {
                // Do some stuff
            }
        }
    };
}

protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    _worker.CancelAsync();
}
```

Comment: After adding the above code I now have the issue inside WindowLauncher on  Dispatcher.Run(); with Similar message "Additional information: Thread was being aborted." any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Background threads are aborted automatically by the runtime when your app exits. Normally they do not throw `ThreadAbortExceptions` (see [Foreground and Background threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Invoking the dispatcher causes a method to be run on the dispatch thread, but since you used `Invoke()` rather than `BeginInvoke()`, the dispatcher needs to inform the background thread that the method finished. I suspect this is where the exception is being raised, but this is only conjecture on my part.

Try catching the exception like this:

```
try
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
         Close();
    }));
}
catch (ThreadAbortException)
{
    Thread.ResetAbort(); 
}
```

Although this may not help if the exception is being raised on the dispatch thread. If this doesn't work then try `BeginInvoke()` instead.

BTW, you can probably reproduce this bug more easily if you stick some kind of delay in the start of your Invoked lambda and close the app at that point. That means the background thread will be aborted by the time the lambda completes.